# is there a way to know which HA namenode is hdfs client connects to through java client code while doing write command?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

How to know which NameNode is client connected to while uploading files to HDFS programmatically from Java?

```
    String fileName = "write_hdfs_example.txt";
    Path hdfsWritePath = new Path("/app/"+fileName);
    FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutputStream = fs.append(hdfsWritePath);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fsDataOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        bufferedWriter.write("append" + i);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("wrote : "+i);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    }
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    fs.close();
```

This is my HDFS client code that writes to a file, I want to know the NameNode info when doing write operation and also how to receive ack from HDFS cluster that data is successfully replicated?

Comment: I don't think you can. That's the whole point of having an HA setup - each node should act and respond the same

Comment: Sure you can, but what would be the use of it? Failover can happen right after :))

Comment: i want to verify if data loss happens when i continuously stream data from client or if there is a delay inbetween failover

Comment: I see, so just to detect a failover once active changes.